# how to slide a div off screen and change style to display: none

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to do this for like a week.... tried everything, just can't figure it out...
I have no idea what to do anymore. Can someone explain or show me how to do this? thanks in advance... much appreciated

query:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#hide-modcraft').click(function(){
            var hidden = $('#modcraft');
            if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
                hidden.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
            } else {
                hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
            }
        });
    });
```

html:

```
<section id="modcraft">
        <div id="prod">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="prod-img modcraft"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="prod-disc">
                            <header>
                                <h1>Modcraft<br/><i>for ps3</i></h1>
                            </header>
                            <footer>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</footer>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="prod-more">
                            <a href="#" id="hide-modcraft"><button>More info</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>
```

css:

```
#modcraft{
position: absolute;
padding: 64px 30px 30px 30px;
background-color: #444;}
```

Comment: ps. i know the tag its trying to move isnt real, but you people always want code samples, but ive tried everything so... just put some bs

Answer (score 0):

I'm entirely clear what you are trying to do from your question, but if you change your click function to include `event.preventDefault();` it seems to work as you intended, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // add "event" to click function
    $('#hide-modcraft').click(function (event) {
        // prevent default click behaviour to allow your script to control
        event.preventDefault();
        var hidden = $('#modcraft');
        if (hidden.hasClass('visible')) {
            hidden.animate({ "left": "-1000px" }, "slow").removeClass('visible');
        } else {
            hidden.animate({ "left": "0px" }, "slow").addClass('visible');
        }
    });
});
```

The panel then moves to the left on the first click, and then slides left from view on the second click. If that's what you intended, then I hope this eases your pain.